# How to implement a pytorch solver that can solve large number of non-linear equations (like scipy.fsolve) parallely, very quickly?

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, pytorch, scipy-optimize

I'm working on a solver for Python, preferably using pytorch tensors that would solve a series of non-linear equations very quickly and efficiently. This solver would essentially need to solve for the variable 's' in the below formula, given a certain value of 'ob'; i.e. the value returned by function 'f' should be zero

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

d = 0.01
r = 0.02
v_base = 0.19
v_skew1 = -0.0035
v_skew2 = -0.0021
t = 1

def v(s):
    return v_base + v_skew1 * (s-1) + v_skew2 * (s-1.1)
def f(s, ob):
    v_temp = v(s)
    k1 = np.log(1/s) + (r - d + 0.5 * v_temp**2)*t)/(v_temp * np.sqrt(t))
    k2 = k1 - v_temp * np.sqrt(t)
    result = np.exp(-d*t) * norm.cdf(k1) - strike * np.exp(-r * t) * norm.cdf(k2)
    return (result - ob)
ob = 0.015 # only one value of ob for now, but need to solve for thousands of ob values
answer = fsolve(f, 0.01, args = ob)
```

ob is going to be calculated using pytorch tensors for performance while solving for a large number of values, so I would prefer that the approach for solving the ob would also use tensors. Also the runtime increases to a lot when I am trying to solve for thousands of 'ob' values even if I pass tensor arguments into fsolve. Is there a way to implement solver functionality of all of these individual fsolves to run parallely using tensors. Also, is there anyway to implement solvers using torch.optim?

Comment: It may help to sort the input ob and use the last solution as starting point for the next solve.